# Template Matching a screenshot fails on assertion

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

I'm trying to use OpenCV for template matching of a screenshot. I'm getting an error whenever I call the `cv::matchTemplate()` function.

**The error I'm getting:**

`OpenCv Error: Assertion failed ((depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_32F) && type == _templ.type() && _img.dims() <= 2) in cv::matchTemplate, file C:\builds\master_PackSlave-win64-vc12-shared\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\templmatch.cpp`

**What I've tried:**

[This question attempts to solve the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29838574/template-matching-from-a-screenshot-of-a-window) but the solution doesn't help because that's what I'm already doing. I've double checked everything in the debugger. Nothing is NULL, everything has several rows and columns and 2 dimensions.

**Main**

```
HWND handle = GetForegroundWindow();
cv::Mat mat;
if (handle != 0){
    mat = windowToMat(handle);
}
myTemplateMatch(mat, playerTemplate);
```

**Template Matching ---**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

#include <ctime>

#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
XYposition myTemplateMatch(cv::Mat &img, cv::Mat &mytemplate)
{
cv::Mat result(img.rows - mytemplate.rows + 1, img.cols - mytemplate.cols + 1, CV_32F);

//***************BREAKS RIGHT HERE****************************
cv::matchTemplate(img, mytemplate, result, CV_TM_SQDIFF_NORMED);
cv::normalize(result, result, 0, 1, cv::NORM_MINMAX, -1, cv::Mat());

double minVal; double maxVal; 
cv::Point minLoc; 
cv::Point maxLoc;
cv::Point matchLoc;

cv::minMaxLoc(result, &minVal, &maxVal, &minLoc, &maxLoc, cv::Mat());
XYposition playerData = {
    maxLoc.x + mytemplate.cols, maxLoc.y + mytemplate.rows
};

rectangle(result, matchLoc, cv::Point(matchLoc.x + mytemplate.cols, matchLoc.y + mytemplate.rows),
    cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255), 4, 8, 0);


cv::namedWindow("cvImage", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
cv::imshow("cvImage", result);
cv::waitKey(0);

return playerData;
}
```

**ScreenShot Creation**

```
cv::Mat windowToMat(HWND hwnd){

HDC hwindowDC, hwindowCompatibleDC;

int height, width, srcheight, srcwidth;
HBITMAP hbwindow;
cv::Mat src;
BITMAPINFOHEADER  bi;

hwindowDC = GetDC(hwnd);
hwindowCompatibleDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hwindowDC);
SetStretchBltMode(hwindowCompatibleDC, COLORONCOLOR);

RECT windowsize;    // get the height and width of the screen
GetClientRect(hwnd, &windowsize);

srcheight = windowsize.bottom;
srcwidth = windowsize.right;
height = windowsize.bottom / 2;  //change this to whatever size you want to resize to
width = windowsize.right / 2;

src.create(height, width, CV_32F);

// create a bitmap
hbwindow = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hwindowDC, width, height);
bi.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
bi.biWidth = width;
bi.biHeight = -height;  //this is the line that makes it draw upside down or not
bi.biPlanes = 1;
bi.biBitCount = 32;
bi.biCompression = BI_RGB;
bi.biSizeImage = 0;
bi.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
bi.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
bi.biClrUsed = 0;
bi.biClrImportant = 0;

// use the previously created device context with the bitmap
SelectObject(hwindowCompatibleDC, hbwindow);
// copy from the window device context to the bitmap device context
StretchBlt(hwindowCompatibleDC, 0, 0, width, height, hwindowDC, 0, 0, srcwidth, srcheight, SRCCOPY); //change SRCCOPY to NOTSRCCOPY for wacky colors !
GetDIBits(hwindowCompatibleDC, hbwindow, 0, height, src.data, (BITMAPINFO *)&bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);  //copy from hwindowCompatibleDC to hbwindow

// avoid memory leak
DeleteObject(hbwindow); DeleteDC(hwindowCompatibleDC); ReleaseDC(hwnd, hwindowDC);

return src;
}
```

Comment: may i see your complete code? i guess there is something missing in this!

Comment: Also have you tried to compile that code separately?

Comment: @BalajiR There wasn't much missing but I added where it was called from. The code complies fine and I can successful call cv::matchTemplate with a non-screenshot template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the type of `Mat` images being used was different. If you use the Mat's `.type()` function you can check the parameters being passed into the function. Cross reference that value with this table

[A Mapping of Type to Numbers in OpenCV](http://ninghang.blogspot.com/2012/11/list-of-mat-type-in-opencv.html)

```
        C1  C2  C3  C4
CV_8U   0   8   16  24
CV_8S   1   9   17  25
CV_16U  2   10  18  26
CV_16S  3   11  19  27
CV_32S  4   12  20  28
CV_32F  5   13  21  29
CV_64F  6   14  22  30
```

and you can change the type of screenshot

`src.create(height, width, CV_32F);` in **Screenshot Creation**

to whatever the value should be.